# Python __init__ and varargs

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

According to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), `__init__` can accept varargs:

```
object.__init__(self[, ...])
```

> Called after the instance has been created (by `__new__()`), but before it is returned to the caller. The arguments are those passed to the class constructor expression. If a base class has an `__init__()` method, the derived class’s `__init__()` method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper initialization of the base class part of the instance; for example:

```
BaseClass.__init__(self, [args...]).
```

I'm struggling to understand how to use varargs on classes that directly derive from `object`. In particular, when trying to instantiate a class that calls `super(<classname>, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`,  I find that if I instantiate the class with no arguments, everything is ok.

However, if I pass arguments to the init function, I get a the error:

```
super(A,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

It is my understanding that `object.__init__` should be able to take parameters based on the documentation -- it also makes writing code easier, as every class can pass its arguments up the class hierarchy.

Is the documentation incorrect, or is `object.__init__` a special case?

Code is below:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i,a in enumerate(args):
            print "arg", i,a
        for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
            print "kwarg", k,v

        super(A,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)




a=A()
print "Done with first one"
a2=A(5,4,5,3)
```

Comment: `object.__init__` doesn’t do anything; I don’t know what the intent of the `[, ...]` there was.

Comment: I found it hard to find the implementation, so I assumed object.__init__ simply ignored its arguments, instead of explicitly not having any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with your interpretation of the docs. In your first line `object.__init__(self[, ...])` is not referring to varargs. It is just saying that there *may* be arguments other than `self` to `__init__`.

`__init__` is not different from any other method in terms of how it is called, by `super`, or any other means. For a less confusing example, take something like [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs). If you pass more than one argument to `abs`, it will raise `TypeError: abs() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`. This is normal and expected. If you pass more arguments to an `__init__` method than it expects, you will get the same error.

A Python method that is not stated to be able to accept varargs will not be able to accept arbitrary arguments. `object.__init__` accepts no arguments. You can all it from your `__init__` as either `object.__init__(self)` or `super(type(self), self).__init__()`.

You can rewrite your example to look like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i, a in enumerate(args):
            print "arg", i, a
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            print "kwarg", k, v

        super(A, self).__init__()
```

This looks pointless at first, since you are extending a class that requires no initialization (`object`). However, even this simple example shows that you can process some of the arguments for your class, and pass others to the base class.

A common idiom is to explicitly name all the child class's arguments (both positional and keyword-only), and let the parent constructor deal with the remainder. For example, consider the following:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Citizen(Person):
    def __init__(self, nationality, *args, **kwargs):
        self.nationality = nationality
        super(Citizen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Declaring `Citizen` to accept varargs *in addition* to the normal arguments is very convenient in this case. You don't have to remember what arguments `Person` accepts, or modify anything if they change. It does not mean that you can call `Citizen.__init__` with completely arbitrary arguments, however. You still have to pass in a total of three arguments, and keywords can only have the names. `nationality`, `name` and `age`. Notice that `Person.__init__` does not even bother to call `object.__init__`.

The important thing to keep in mind is that all the real classes you will be dealing with, whether from the Python libraries or external sources, should be well documented enough to tell you what you can and can't pass in. Just because something technically accepts varargs, does not mean that it does not have restrictions on what can be passed in.

Answer (score 1):

`object` is only a special case in that there is nothing to initialize, so its constructor doesn't accept any args or kwargs. Since the `__init__` method on `object` doesn't do anything there's no need to call it if you're inheriting only from `object`.

Comment: object is not special in the sense that constructors are not obligated to accept any arguments besides the ones stated. object happens not to accept any at all, but that is perfectly normal. It's no different when range raises an error if you try to pass in four arguments.

Comment: While I understand what you're saying, it is indeed a "special case" and I explained why immediately after. I hardly think it's downvote worthy...

Comment: What comes after is true for any class that does not require initialization. There are many such classes. The only special feature I am aware of with object is that all new style classes inherit from it.

Comment: It's "special" because it's basic and there's nothing to initialize. That's all there is to it. I wasn't saying it's special because magic... And I'm not saying you're wrong, but I don't think our points really conflict with each other...

Comment: My main objection is not with what you are saying as much as the fact that you are using "special case" in a very different sense than OP and glossing over the detail in the question.

Comment: Did you read what I said after that? It's special because there's nothing to initialize, so you never need to call the `super` method for it. That's why it's special. I'm not "glossing over" anything. Like I said, I understand what you're saying, but it seems to me you're just being pedantic.

Comment: FWIW I've updated my answer to hopefully be phrased a little better.

Comment: It seems inconsistent with the documentation... I'm surprised that they simply didn't just ignore arguments rather than requiring that you adhere to a signature.

Comment: It's very consistent, @gbronner. If you define a function like this: `def some_func(arg1): print(arg1)` but you call it like `print('joe', 'schmoe')` it's going to give you an error.

Answer (score -3):

`super()` is defective by design IMHO. See here: https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/

In short:

- it interoperates badly with the old calling style
- you must never forget it
- you cannot change method signature on subclasses
- you cannot even be sure in what order the methods will be called
- multiple-inheritance is a recipe for confusion anyways.

You wrote the code, you should know the hierarchy. Just use `MySuperclass.__foobar__(self, etc)`. Works all the time.

Comment: `super ()` works perfectly fine when you understand how it works.

Comment: Well yes, but it has the mentioned drawbacks that make it impractical. Especially the __init__ method is one where you often want another signature in a subclass (e.g. add properties or omit meaningless parameters), which collides with super()s restrictions.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from calling `super(xxx, yyy)` with different params than the one your subclass expects. And yes, `super()` does obviously not work when your class hierarchy is so inconsistant that each class expects differents arguments for the same method, but then that's a huge design smell and you may want to question your use of inheritance (maybe composition/delegation would be a best fit in this case).

Comment: Using different parameters in the super call means that you expect a certain sub/superclass's implementation to be called, which is exactly what is *not* guaranteed (see the linked article). And that was my argument - if you rely on a specific call order, why not hardcode it.

Comment: contrived example for changing signature: suppose you have a class Ellipse(a, b) with a, b being the halfaxes. You might want to have a subclass Circle(R) --> calling Ellipse(a=R, b=R).

Comment: This contrived example is just a variation of the famous `rectangle / square` case where while a square is (in geometry) a specific case of a `rectangle` it's  not a proper subtype from an OO pov (cf liskov etc). And using different parameters in the `super()` call only means that you know that _your current subclass_ (the one making the call)_ is not a proper subtype of it's parents. That's a common use case when extending some framework's base class (like `Form` in Django or some `Window` class in a GUI toolkit etc), and doesn't mean you should not use `super()` either.